# sending multiple image path to the server?

Tags: android, asynchronous, http-post, androidhttpclient

I have written the below code in `doInBackground`,

```
InputStream in = null;
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
try {
    System.out.println("calling API here");
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("my url"); 
    MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();

    if (imageList !=  null) {
        for(int i=0;i<imageList.size();i++) {

            File f= new File(imageList.get(i));
            in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
            reqEntity.addPart("file[]",f.getName(), in);    

            }
        }

    reqEntity.addPart("mobile",owner_mobile);   
    reqEntity.addPart("reg_code",reg_code);
    reqEntity.addPart("book_id",book_id);
    reqEntity.addPart("adv_amount",advAmountValue);

    httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);

    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

The problem is when I am sending `multiple image(s)` to the `server` , only first image`(for e.g, 23457352.jpg)` is sending others are not.

can anyone help me to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Is that your full code?  You have unclosed `try` and `if` statements.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use index in attribute name.

```
for(int i=0;i<imageList.size();i++){

                                File f= new File(imageList.get(i));
                                in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
                                reqEntity.addPart("file[" + i + "]",f.getName(), in);    

                                }
                            }
```

Comment: I am getting same result.  here my ArrayList<String> imageList contains size of 3 , but only one  image path sending to server.